# Analyzing a CSV file using Django Pandas and Pyplot

Tags: python, django, csv, matplotlib, pandas

So I am currently working on a Django web app that allows for users to upload CSV files, analyze those files, and then present a graph back to the client. The CSVs that will inputted are generated from Matlab and all describe the same general type of data, but the formatting of each file is different depending on how the user exported the data from Matlab. My problem is there is no standard to how the files are to be formatted so I have to dynamically check the CSV file upon uploading and then generate the correct graph accordingly. I think this is best demonstrated in an example.

#### Example CSV data for velocity and force

```
Shock Name, 
Shock ID, 
Vehicle, 
Location, 
Compression Valving, 
Rebound Valving, 
Piston Valving, 
Other Valving, 
Compression Setting, 
Rebound Setting, 
Preload Setting, 
Notes, 
, 
Measured_Stroke, 2.00 in
Seal_Drag, 7.77 lbs
Test_Temperature, 73.63 F
Peak_Velocity, 12.47 in/sec
, 
Amplitude, 1.00 in
Test_Period, 0.00 sec
Gas_Force, 34.78 lbs
Test_Speed, 12.21 in/sec


Velocity, CO, RC, CC, RO, CA, RA
in/sec, lbs, lbs, lbs, lbs, lbs, lbs
0, -139.3172, -138.4583, 33.49831, 34.24039, -52.90947, -52.10897
1, 2.637415, -353.36, 119.1066, -98.40744, 60.87201, -225.8837
2, 92.96767, -423.1163, 136.1344, -293.0744, 114.551, -358.0953
3, 117.664, -445.5688, 144.661, -417.9908, 131.1625, -431.7798
4, 126.363, -460.8381, 151.5483, -456.5551, 138.9557, -458.6966
5, 133.3087, -474.8662, 158.4935, -473.8318, 145.9011, -474.349
6, 139.7847, -487.5624, 163.9969, -486.3072, 151.8908, -486.9348
7, 146.0275, -500.0915, 168.9006, -497.6936, 157.464, -498.8926
8, 152.5096, -512.0554, 174.573, -508.9675, 163.5413, -510.5115
9, 160.0202, -524.4933, 178.737, -519.4616, 169.3786, -521.9774
10, 166.6279, -534.5439, 182.7012, -529.475, 174.6645, -532.0095
11, 174.6142, -545.5678, 186.8209, -541.7671, 180.7175, -543.6675
12, 183.1358, -556.0939, 188.4442, -553.749, 185.79, -554.9215
```

Everything before the Velocity box is merely a large settings header that can vary from file to file depending on the user's settings in Matlab. Velocity should be the index column in that each row is a velocity step in time. Each column after Velocity is labeled with an acronym (e.g. CO, RC, CC, etc.) which all need to be graphed according to the velocity time step.

My attempted implementation is as follows:

```
# graph input file
def graph(request):
    # graph style
    pd.set_option('display.mpl_style', 'default')
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15,5)

    new_file = request.session.get('docFile')
    fig = Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_xlabel("Time")
    ax.set_ylabel("Velocity")
    data_df = pd.read_csv(new_file, header=28)
    data_df = pd.DataFrame(data_df)
    data_df.plot(ax=ax, title="Roehrig Shock Data", style="-o")
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    response = HttpResponse( content_type = 'image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    return response
```

This presents a graph correctly, but I am hard-coding `header=28` as the line that Velocity falls on.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to dynamically scan the CSV for the Velocity and then start the header there?
2. How can I label each line plot as the name of the corresponding column acronym?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to browse through the entire file with a regular `open` statement and parse your headers dynamically before using panda.

For instance:

```
import re
import panda as pd

raw_data = open('your_file.csv', 'rb').read()
rows  = re.split('\n', raw_data)

for idx, row in enumerate(rows):
    cells = row.split(',')
    if 'Velocity' in cells:
        header_names = cells    # this will be something like ['Velocity', ' CO', ' RC', ...]
        header_row   = idx
        break

# Now you have the header line as well as the custom header names.
# You can start using pandas.read_csv
pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', header=header_row)

# ...

# and use `header_names` for your plots.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked great for finding the header row. I'm trying to set the index column and header names but haven't been able to get it. Here is what I have so far: data_df = data_df.set_index(keys = header_names) but it keeps giving me a KeyError

Comment: But why? Why can't we use pandas